# Adicionar "nome" em um objeto do JSON

Tags: php, json

Meu JSON atualmente retorna esse código baixo:

```
{"2":"aluno","8":"barbara_cristina","13":"carolina_deus"}
```

Tem como nos lugares dos numeros 2, 8 e13 eu adicionar um "cabeçalho"? Queria que ficasse assim:

```
{"nome":"aluno","nome":"barbara_cristina","nome":"carolina_deus"}
```

Estes são os comandos que uso para gerar o JSON.

```
$aluno = array();    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica))
{ 
   $aluno[]= $row['username'];
} 

$alunoToledo = array(); 
while($lista2 = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica2))
{  
   $alunoToledo[] = $lista2['username'];
}

$result = array_diff($aluno,$alunoToledo);
json_encode($result)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar, se for possível isso?

Comment: Clique em [edit] e ponha o código que gera o JSON. O que você quer é bem simples, mas precisamos do código pra ajudar melhor (a parte que obtém os valores, não só o `encode`). No caso, seria por um nome nos objetos, e não um "cabeçalho". Os objetos do JSON são definidos como `"nome":valor`. http://json.org/ Provavelmente esses números estão vindo de algum _array_, e é lá que temos que ajustar os nomes, antes do encode.

Comment: Pronto, já alterei

Comment: desenhe a saída do json que você espera, para que a gente faça aqui.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta, deixando ela mais completa, com os comandos que utilizei para gerar, como fica, e como quero deixar...obrigado :d

Comment: Melhorou bastante com a sua edição, mas repetir os nomes não dá. Cada par precisa de um nome único. Se quer o mesmo nome, vai ficar diferente o formato. Para criar coisas com o mesmo nome, vai ficar como um array de pares: `[{"nome":"maria"},{"nome":"pedro"},{"nome":"zuul"}]`, senão nao é um JSON válido.

Comment: vc quer mudar as chaves numéricas para texto, entendi. Só não entendi de onde veio essa variável `$variavel` , não seria o `$result`?

Comment: não tem como então?

Comment: Conforme desenhado, não dá pra fazer com JSON. Daria pra gerar como string, mas depende muito de onde vai usar. Se a parte que vai receber os dados quiser um JSON, tem que ser conforme eu postei no comentário acima, um array de objetos:  `[{"nome":"maria"},{"nome":"pedro"},{"nome":"zuul"}]`

Comment: dá sim, só me explica o que você está fazendo... de onde está saindo essa variável `$variavel`. Seu código não parece estar completo.

Comment: Alterei la, onde era $variavel coloquei $result

Comment: Só não entendi porque vc quer dessa forma, pois não é um json correto, mas... dá pra fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só precisa transformar o seu `json` em `array`:

Converte isso: `{"nome":"aluno","nome":"barbara_cristina","nome":"carolina_deus"}`

Nisto: `[{"nome":"aluno"},{"nome":"barbara_cristina"},{"nome":"carolina_deus"}]`

Não entendo muito de php, mas você precisa criar um array desta forma:

```
$alunos= array( array( 'nome' => $aluno ), array( 'nome'....
```

mais info: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/array.php

Comment: Sim, é o que eu estou tentando fazer, como faria?

Answer (score 5):

Para fazer isso, basta agregar as chaves:

```
$aluno = array();    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica))
{ 
$aluno[]= $row['username'];
} 

$alunoToledo = array(); 
while($lista2 = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica2))
{  
$alunoToledo[] = $lista2['username'];
}

$results = array_diff($aluno,$alunoToledo);
echo '{nome:' . $results[0] . ',nome:' . $results[1] . ',nome:' . $results[2] . '}';
```

Porém o uso de JSON, não é válido desta forma, pois quando se usa JSON, deve se ter uma chave para cada um, seria algo similar a isso:

```
[{nome: "nome1"},{nome: "nome2"},{nome: "nome3"},{nome: "nome4"}]
```

E sendo assim, você deveria fazer desta forma:

```
$collection = array();
foreach ($results as $result){
    $collection[]['nome'] = $result;  
}

echo json_encode($collection);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### É possível, mas é esquisito

O que está tentando fazer é um objeto JSON com chaves/propriedades repetidas. Isso é incomum pois muitas bibliotecas JSON vão dar erro ao ler um JSON com chaves repetidas, e mesmo que não dê erro, provavelmente não vão permitir ler os dados todos. Usando seu exemplo de querer um resultado:

> {"nome":"aluno","nome":"barbara_cristina","nome":"carolina_deus"}

Ao fazer:

```
$obj = json_decode( $json );
echo $obj->nome;
```

Você espera que imprima o que? `aluno`, `barbara_cristina` ou `carolina_deus`?

#### Não é possível de fazer com `json_encode()`

Porque `json_encode()` não produz objetos com chaves repetidas. Tem de fazer gambi na mão. Algo assim:

```
<?php
$result = array( "2" => "aluno" , "8" => "barbara_cristina" , "13" => "carolina_deus" );

$fakeItens = array();
foreach ( $result as $item )
    $fakeItens[] = '"nome":' . json_encode( $item );
$fakeJson = "{" . implode( ',' , $fakeItens ) . "}";
echo $fakeJson;
```

Esse código vai gerar JSON correto, mesmo no caso que o item tenha aspas ou caracteres especiais.

#### Em vez de colocar um cabeçalho fixo, tirar as chaves?

Parece que as chaves numéricas que estão incomodando. Se o "cabeçalho" for uma coisa fixa, que tal *não* colocar ele, e sim tirar os números?

```
<?php
$result = array( "2" => "aluno" , "8" => "barbara_cristina" , "13" => "carolina_deus" );
echo json_encode( array_values( $result ) );
```

Compare o resultado dos dois códigos:

```
{"nome":"aluno","nome":"barbara_cristina","nome":"carolina_deus"}
["aluno","barbara_cristina","carolina_deus"]
```